# javascript function works only on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

I made a function that shows card images after I click a button. the problem is that it doesn't work on chrome. the chrome editor presents an extra '/' to the end of the path.

```
        function renderDeck(deck,ph)
    {
        
        var htmlStr = document.getElementById(ph).innerHTML;
        for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
            htmlStr += '<div>';
            htmlStr += '<img src=' + deck[i].path + '/>';
            htmlStr += '</div>';
        }
        document.getElementById(ph).innerHTML = htmlStr;
    }
```

An example of what I push inside the deck

```
deck.push({ name: 'red_joker', path: 'cardImages/red_joker.png', val: 15 });
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: try `htmlStr += '<img src="' + deck[i].path + '"/>';`

Comment: You've marked the question with html tag, HTML doesn't contain self-closing tags, though browsers are tolerating them. Also, you always should quote the attribute values, it's a security risk to not do so (maybe not in this particular case, but the better the sooner you unlearn bad practices).

Answer (score 0):

Off Topic: Avoid `innerHTML += ...` because

- it has to serialize and then parse all existing dom nodes
- it replaces all existing nodes with copies/new ones, so things like event handler, references you've kept, all will be gone.
  Everything that is not expressed in the markup itself.

```
function renderDeck(deck, ph) {
  // create the markup for the new items 
  const htmlStr = deck.map(item => `<div><img src="${item.path}"></div>`).join("\n");

  // parse the `htmlStr` into a DOM Node that you can add to other DOM Nodes. 
  const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlStr);

  // append the DocumentFragment to the existing element.
  document.getElementById(ph).append(fragment);
}
```

And a link for those that don't know yet what a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) is.

Comment: Though true, this really is off-topic, OP never wrote `innerHTML +=`, they retrieved `innerHTML` to a string, added more content to that string and then reassigned it to the element.

Comment: @Teemu that's only a superficial difference. Like the difference between `return stuff;` and `var result = stuff; return result;`. Can you tell me any difference in behavior between the two codes? Especially in regard to the problems I mentioned above. OK, the memory allocations will be slightly different, but that's well beyond OPs question AND my answer.

Comment: If OP would had done `element.innerHTML += ...`  in the loop, I'd understand the answer well. But OP is not preserving the existing HTML in `#ph`, the element content is overridden (if there is content, the question doesn't tell). But I can agree with you, the only legitimate use of setting  `innerHTML` of an existing element is to empty the element.